# Size of dyn MyTrait cannot be statically determined in method which takes self?

Tags: rust

I'm creating a `HashMap<u64, Box<dyn MyTrait>>`. I can create the `HashMap` and insert a struct that implements `MyTrait`, but when I retrieve `MyTrait` and try to use it, the compiler complains at me:

```
error[E0161]: cannot move a value of type dyn MyTrait: the size of dyn MyTrait cannot be statically determined
```

I was under the impression that a trait consists of two pointers, one to the vtable and one to the object data. So the size of any trait, including `MyTrait`, should be `2 * pointer_size`. Furthermore, the object data pointer points to a `MyStruct`, which is of known size. Clearly I'm wrong in my understanding but I can't figure out why.

Here's my code:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
  let mut hm: HashMap<u64, Box<dyn MyTrait>> = HashMap::new();
  hm.insert(0, Box::new(MyStruct{num: 0}));
  match hm.get(&(0 as u64)) {
    Some(r) => {
      r.my_fun();
      }
    None => { println!("not found");}
  }
}

pub trait MyTrait {
  fn my_fun(self);
}

struct MyStruct {
  num: u64,
}

impl MyTrait for MyStruct {
  fn my_fun(self) {
    println!("num is {}", self.num);
    return
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

When you declared the method in `MyTrait` as `fn my_fun(self);`, this creates a method that takes the `self` parameter by *value*, not by reference. In Rust, there is no implicit clone for most values (and for those that do, it only supports a straight-forward bit-per-bit copy).

In general, passing a parameter by value results in it being *moved*, and afterwards its old location is no longer valid and becomes invalid behavior to somehow access. (Although that this doesn't happen is enforced by the compiler.)

The error isn't saying that you can't have a `Box<dyn MyTrait>` in the value of a `HashMap`, but rather that you cannot move a `dyn MyTrait` out of the `&Box<dyn MyTrait>` reference you had gotten from the `hm.get` call. Even if you had a sized type there instead of an unsized one, this is still not possible because you cannot move a value out from behind a shared reference, unless the type is `Copy`. (In which case, it is, well, copied instead of moved at all.)

Most likely, you want to use `fn my_fun(&self)` instead, which takes the self parameter by reference instead of value.

If you want to mutate the value in the function, you should declare the function `fn my_fun(&mut self)` and replace the `hm.get` with `hm.get_mut` so you have a mutable reference to your `MyStruct`.

If you really need to take the self parameter by value instead of reference, you can write `fn my_fun(self: Box<Self>)` which declares that the self parameter is a boxed value, and then change the `hm.get` line to `hm.remove`. As the name implies, this leaves the value no longer accessible in the hash map.